# Почему не работает редактирование input на некоторых андроид смартфонах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Данный код работает на ios, ПК, на некоторых андроидах но..не работает в s7 в гугл хроме, ошибка именно на уровне установки точки (скрипт автоматически ставит точку межу датой), при этом подсчет символов идет корректно (дебажил алертами на смартфоне), в чем мб причина? Интересует именно причина ошибки (проблему решил использованием сторонней либы, а вот докопаться до истины так и не получилось, покоя не дает, спать не могу!)

```
$(function () {
    var allowable_values = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.'];
    var date_fields = $('.date');

    date_fields.keydown(function(e){
        var inp = $(this);
        console.log(e.which);
        if (allowable_values.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) >= 0)  {
               if (inp.val().length == 2 | inp.val().length == 5) {
                   //это условие сработало, а точки не ставится
                   inp.val(inp.val() + '.');
               }
               return true;

        } else if ( e.which == 8 | e.which == 39 | e.which == 37){
           return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Там иногда происходят странные вещи, связанные со свайпом или т9. У меня похожая проблема была с энтером.

Comment: Решили проблему? На айфоне у меня тоже свайп клавиатура, и на удивления тапы работают нормально, я тоже подумал об этом, но вот незадача, в фаерфосе на том же устройстве все работает

Comment: Решил также, как и вы. Подключил библиотеку)